# How can I solve NDSolve with a parameter?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I'm a new user and I have no idea how to solve the equation with a parameter by using `NDSolve`. For example consider following differential equation (DE):

```
sol = y'[x] + (y[x] + k) == 0;
```

where `k` is a parameter. I want to solve this DE and plot with `k` range.

```
Plot[y[x]./x->3, {k, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: ParametricNDSolve.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not specified an initial condition, I have decided to use it as one of the parameters. Modify as you see fit.

```
eq = y'[x] + (y[x] + k) == 0;
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, y[0] == y0}, y, {x, 0, 3.5}, {k, y0}];
Plot[sol[k, 0][3], {k, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.